# Save dynamic content in Chrome on a Windows tablet

Tags: google-chrome, windows

I have written a few web pages that get some user data via forms over the course of these pages, store it as cookies, and then get the cookies and tabulate the information on the last page by doing `$(document).ready(retrieveCookieValues);`, writing it to a dedicated `<div>`. I'm using JQuery 2.1.1 to access and manipulate the DOM. I used to be able to store this information at the last page easily by saving the web page.

Sometime yesterday, Chrome 36.0.1985.125m with --enable-file-cookies stopped saving the dynamically-generated content (it still displays it on the page, just doesn't save it). I haven't changed any code in between when it was working and when it wasn't, so I'm baffled why this would happen. I've restarted the tablet, cleared out the browser data, etc. I am using Chrome because:

- Firefox doesn't have a Windows browser that works with touch interface
- IE requires specific javascript and CSS to get the pages to work (I've tried; the IE engine can't render the pages correctly, unlike every other browser)

Unfortunately, I don't have the possibility to do this server-side; it has to be done on the Windows 8 tablet I've been given (making my life a bit of a headache).

Any suggestions why this would occur, and how I can fix the issue?

Comment: @pnuts I figured that "Features of browsers which are directly related to the use of a web application" made this one on-topic. Point taken; I'll ask elsewhere.

Comment: Transfer to Stack Overflow then? The Q&A is still probably useful for anyone trying to identify this particular bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a similar issue in this thread:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/yXMeKOMEh3o/HccTr4VdF3YJ

In my case, it turns out that my version of Chrome is saving the html only version of the page and losing lots of data in the process (dynamic content and all of the js, css, etc files). Solution: get a different build.